# JSP Chat - How I can parse the value from HTML to JSP page?

Tags: javascript, java, html, jsp, request

I have to make a chat with JSP, AJAX and Java and I have a problem: when I try to use my variable to store value of a input text, this variable is null.
If I add 'action' property to the form, the variable 'textParam' will have the value of the input text, but, if I do that I have to redirect with action to a page and I don't what that.

I need to process something bigger in the JSP page and then to reload in the HTML page (which is a JSP page) (the reload part is not on actual probem).

How I can make to populate 'textParam' with the input text value when I press the button?

PS: I need to make it with pure javascript, not with some libraries :)

The JSP which have to process is:

```
String textParam = request.getParameter("chatMessage");
System.out.println("textParam = " + textParam);
```

My form it look like that:

```
<form id="frmmain" name="frmmain" onsubmit="return blockSubmit();">
        <input type="text" id="chatMessage" name="chatMessage" style="width: 447px;" />
        <input type="button" name="btn_send_chat" id="btn_send_chat" value="Send" onclick="sendChatText();" />
</form>
```

The .js file it's this:

```
var request = getXmlHttpRequestObject();
var response = getXmlHttpRequestObject();
var lastMessage = 0;
var mTimer;

function getXmlHttpRequestObject() {                
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {                    
        return new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else if(window.ActiveXObject) {                   
        return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
}

function sendChatText() {
    if(document.getElementById('chatMessage').value == '') {
        alert("You have not entered a message");
        return;
    }
    if (request.readyState == 4 || request.readyState == 0) {
        request.open("POST", 'getChat2.jsp?chat=1&last=' + lastMessage, true);
        request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        request.onreadystatechange = handleSendChat; 
        var param = 'message=' + document.getElementById('chatMessage').value;                                  
        param += '&chat=1';
        request.send(param);
        document.getElementById('chatMessage').value = '';
    }                           
}

function handleSendChat() {             
    clearInterval(mTimer);
    getChatText();
}

function blockSubmit() {
    sendChatText();
    return false;
}
```

Comment: well, your code seems to be getting the text because document.getElementById('chatMessage').value must contain the text you want. Isn't your question about the getChatText() javascript function?

Comment: yes, I want to take the text from document.getElementById('chatMessage').value and to make a Java variable in another page

Comment: I see. have you tried to store the conversation on the server side in a common context for both pages? Can your solution use Servlets?

Comment: I tried something, but I'm not very experimented. If it isn't any solution, I will accept the servlets.

Comment: I won't lie to you, there are several chat implementations up there, so you can just google a little. :-) try github too, so you can get the source code. One fine tutorial I've found was this one -- http://ben-bai.blogspot.com.br/2012/01/jsp-practice-simple-chat.html -- good luck!

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will look there to study. For moment I found the problem: String textParam = request.getParameter("message");   I was thinking that the 'chatMessage' is the parameter, but it was 'messages'

Comment: Great. In this case, I suggest you to post your answer and accept it, so your post can help someone else in the future

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
String textParam = request.getParameter("chatMessage");
```

I was trying to get 'chatMessage' parameter, which it was only the name of the input. The solve is to get 'message' param which it was defined and requested in js:

```
String textParam = request.getParameter("message");
```